# Read properties file from GWT

Tags: gwt, properties, rpc

I got this kind of error. when trying to read a properties file It works fine in development mode but when I trying to deploy app to tomcat this error is comes.

```
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object     not found in the classpath
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:616)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:390)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Make sure your RPC functions on the server side have catch clause for the exception. You cannot pass the FileNotFoundException (and many exceptions) to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make an Rpc call, the classes involved must implement `java.io.Serializable`. In your case, this might have happened.

In your `service class` methods you somewhere mentioned one of the arguments or return type as `java.io.FileNotFoundException` which does not implement `java.io.Serializable`. Hence it cannot be serialized.

**EDIT :** This might help you [Serialization Exception while making an RPC call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303223/serialization-exception-while-making-an-rpc-call/14303313#14303313)

Comment: Every `Throwable` implements `Serializable`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

Comment: Just saw the link. I dint Knew it. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Every exception that could go to the client-side has to be declared in a `throws` clause in your `RemoteService` interface.

If it's working in DevMode, it's probably because you don't have such an exception. You have to find the cause of the `FileNotFoundException`.