# Serialization Exception while making an RPC call

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

I have created a very basic application. I have only one service class and a corresponding Async class which contains only Java types and no custom classes. But still I get the serialization exception.

My service class looks like this.

```
public interface MyService extends RemoteService {
  public String getName();
  public Object getAdditionalDetials(ArrayList<String> ids);
  public Date getJoiningDate();
}
```

My async interface looks like this

```
public interface MyServiceAsync {
  public void getName(AsyncCallback<String> callback);
  public void getAdditionalDetials(ArrayList<String> ids, AsyncCallback<Object> callback);
  public void getJoiningDate(AsyncCallback<Date> callback);
}
```

I know I am making some stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Naive in gwt rpc and serialization mechanism, but will try to answer your question.

Whenever you write classes involving an RPC, GWT creates a `Serialization Policy File`. The serialization policy file contains a whitelist of allowed types which may be serialized.

In your Service methods, all the types you mention and refer will be automatically added to this list if they implements [`IsSerializable`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html). In your case you have used the following two methods,

```
public String getName();
public Date getJoiningDate();
```

Here you have used `String` and `Date` as your return types and hence it is added to your `Serialization Policy File`. But in the below method their lies a problem,

```
public Object getAdditionalDetials(Arraylist<String> ids);
```

Here you have used `ArrayList and String` that is not a problem and they will be added to your whitelist, but the problem is you have mentioned return type as `Object`. Here GWT Compiler does not know what type to be added to `whitelist or Serialization Policy` and hence it wont pass your RPC call. The solution is use mention a class which implements [`IsSerializable`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html) instead of mentioning the return type of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was having this problem but my 'Object' type was **hidden behind generified classes**.

So if one of your rpc methods involves a class:

```
class Xxx<T> implements IsSerializable {...
```

It needs to change to:

```
class Xxx<T extends IsSerializable> implements IsSerializable {...
```