# Using Generics with GWT-RPC isn't working as expected

Tags: java, generics, gwt, gwt-rpc

Rather than creating a hundred different GWT-RPC service and serviceAsync classes, I'm trying to create a single service using generics. Here's the interface:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("dispatch")
public interface CommandService extends RemoteService
{
    public <T> Result<T> execute(Command command, T target);
}
```

Here `Command` is an enum of all the different commands that I can issue, such as `Login, Register, ChangePassword`', etc. On the server-side, I have a `HashMap` of `Command` as the key, and an `Executor` class as the value. For each `Command` I have a corresponding `Executor`. That `Executor` is executed, and its return value is returned on the server-side.

The problem occurs when I try to create `CommandServiceAsync` on the client, and attempt to execute it. Here's my code for that:

```
public enum Command
{
    LOGIN,
    REGISTER,
    CHANGE_PW;

    public <T> void execute(T target, final ResultReceiver<T> receiver)
    {
        CommandServiceAsync command = GWT.create(CommandService.class );
        command.execute(this, target, new AsyncCallback<Result<T> >()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
            {
                MyProgram.handleFailure(caught);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Result<T> result)
            {
                receiver.receive( result );;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here, `Command.execute` is the method which actually calls the service. Here's how I'm calling it to execute the `LOGIN` command:

```
LoginForm form = new LoginForm();
Command.LOGIN.execute(form, new ResultReceiver<LoginForm>()
{
    @Override
    public void receive(Result<LoginForm> result)
    {
        Console.debug("Received result");
        //result.getTarget() will return an instance of LoginForm
        Console.debug("user: " + result.getTarget().getUser() );
        Console.debug("pw: " + result.getTarget().getUser() );
    }
});
```

The problem is happening on the following line in `Command.execute`:

```
CommandServiceAsync command = GWT.create(CommandService.class );
```

Here, I get the following errors:

> ERROR: Deferred binding failed for 'com.xxx.CommandService'; expect
> subsequent failures
>
> ERROR: Uncaught exception escaped
> com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught:
> Deferred binding failed for 'com.xxx.CommandService' (did you forget
> to inherit a required module?)
>
> Caused by:
> com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log
> entries)

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

In client-side GWT applications, all types must be known at compile time. Having a generic method like the one you've described simply won't work.

You could try something like the following

```
public interface CommandService extends RemoteService {
    public Result<Serializable> execute(Command command, Serializable target);
}
```

You will lose some type-safety and restrict you a bit, but that should work.

[Request Factory](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) may be a better fit in this situation. It offers a lot of leniency as to where the server-side code does the actual work.

There is a Request Factory sample project available in the GWT source. The gwtproject.org website has pretty clear instructions on getting the source code, [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html#workingoncode). Look at the README file in the `eclipse` directory. That will help you get started.

**Edit:**

As @ColinAlworth pointed out, you should be **VERY CAREFUL** when using simple interfaces in your RPC methods. The method above is telling the compiler that it should be able to send **every Serializable object** over the wire which it has access to, and will create serializers and deserializers for each and every single one!

Comment: Be very careful with this - you are explicitly telling the compiler that it can send *any* serializable object over the wire. The RPC generator will pick out any Serializable that GWT has access to, and will build serializers and deserializers for it and compiling the type in, even if you never use those types elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Using genrics and Object classes for GWT-RPC is a bad approach. Some time it will throw a serialization exception, some times it won't but it won't work. The reason for this is, GWT creates **whitelist or Serialization Policy** at compile time. For this, you need to know the exact classes you are using.
For more details on this, check out the below link

[Serialization Exception while making an RPC call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303223/serialization-exception-while-making-an-rpc-call/14303313#14303313)

Comment: What's the best way to use the command pattern with GWT then?

Comment: Command pattern are one of design patterns that is recommended for programing with gwt. If you observe, even AsyncCallback is an example for it. But for gwt -rpc you cannot use command patterns which involves Generics. It must be concrete class which implements Serializable or IsSeralizable

Comment: I see. But I don't understand how the command pattern can be used for things like caching gwt requests in that case. I've watched a video on it, where he made an Action and `Response` interface. Then he made a ContactService GWT interface which took a <T extends Action> as his argument, and returned a <T extends Response>. But I don't see why even using `Action` and `Response` is necessary in that case. And how can it be used to implement caching? Any ideas?

Comment: Using `T extends Action` tells the compiler that only `Action` subclasses can be sent over the wire, which drastically reduces the serialization code it needs to generate (and will end up in your JS code). See @Jonathan's answer.